# How to get attachment file name not attachment URL

Tags: attachments, get-posts

I'm using this code to list the image attachments of a post:

```
      <select name="chb_homes_for_sale_specifics_floor_plan" style="width:100%;">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'numberposts'     => -1,
            'orderby'         => 'menu_order',
            'order'           => 'ASC',
            'post_type'       => 'attachment',
            'post_parent'     => $post->ID,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image'
        );
        $image = get_posts($args);
        if($image) {
            foreach($image as $key => $data) : ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $data->ID; ?>"><?php echo $data->post_title; ?></option>

            <?php endforeach;
        }
        ?>
      </select>
```

But what I'm showing currently is the attachment `post_title` but I want to show the file name instead. I could maybe use get attachment URL then parse the URL to get the file name but was wondering if there is a ready made way in WordPress to get the file name.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would strongly advise against using `$post->guid` - WordPress now generates them in the form;

> http:/example.com/?attachment_id=ID

Use the same method that many of the attachment-related functions use;

```
$filename = basename ( get_attached_file( $data->ID ) );
```

Comment: And [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/wp-hackers/DOG5Q0ocGLs/discussion) is the link to the discussion

Comment: link is dead :(