# How to single click to download image in single post

Tags: attachments, media

i have attacment.php like this.

```
<?php  

if ( $attachments = get_children( array(  
'post_type' => 'attachment',  
'post_mime_type'=>'image',  
'numberposts' => 1,  
'post_status' => null,  
'post_parent' => $post->ID  
)));
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {  
echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, '' , false, true, 'Download This Wallpaper');  
}  
?>
```

this code will print attachment link.

My question is: How to make this link to be single click to download image and save to computer user?

Comment: What do you mean by 'single click to download'? What is happening right now when you click on the link?

Comment: if I click it now it appears to the page where I upload an image, not downloaded. example example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/filename.jpg link.  my question is there a script or combined with the addition of javascript to create this image directly downloaded by the user, without having to right click - SAVE IMAGE AS.

Comment: Well, then this is no WP-specific question. Please have a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090272/how-can-i-force-a-image-download).

Comment: if you could identify your file type of attachment, you could set the page headers of attachment.php to the right mime type and that should force the browser to download (maybe)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by using the plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-shortcode/

I am here to assist you since I am using the same functionnality in my website (force dowloading of post attachements)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not WP-specific, here's how to *force* the user to download an image:

```
if ( $attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'=>'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
) ) );
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);"
        onclick="document.execCommand(\'SaveAs\', true, \'' . get_permalink( $attachment->ID ) . '\');">
        Download This Wallpaper</a>';
}
```

**Note**: the code is untested.

Comment: i have tested your code, but the Javascript is not work well. how resolve this.

Comment: hi there, with my code above, i want to ask how to open the link in `_blank` format or open in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following as `image.php` on your theme:

```
<?php

// This forces all image attachments to be downloaded instead of displayed on the browser.
// For it to work, this file needs to be called "image.php".
// For more info, refer to the wp hierarchy diagram.

// Get the path on disk. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/20087/22510
global $wp_query;
$file = get_attached_file($wp_query->post->ID);

// Force the browser to download. Source: https://wpquestions.com/7521
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: public'); //for i.e.
header('Pragma: public');

// ob_clean(); // Looks like we don't need this
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```