# Trying to get file name

Tags: post-meta

I have a custom meta box to store pdf files. For this input, I'm using type="media" to acess wordpress media library.

Now I can't get the file name. Here is my entire loop:

```
<ul>
        <?php
        $args_artigos = array('post_type' => 'artigo','posts_per_page' => -1);
        $artigos_posts = new WP_Query($args_artigos);

        if($artigos_posts->have_posts()) : 
           while($artigos_posts->have_posts()) : 
           $artigos_posts->the_post();
        ?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="artigos-titulo"><?php the_title() ?></a>
        <span class="artigos-autor"><?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'autor', true ) ); ?></span>
        <?php $filename = basename ( get_attached_file( get_the_ID() ) ); echo $filename; ?>


        </li>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
           Oops, there are no posts.
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
```

But it's return no data.

Comment: [see this answer.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/20087/4771)

Comment: @Milo same error. See my entire loop.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your first code block isn't included in your second code block (entire loop markup).

Comment: you can't just copy/paste that code into yours, you need to pass the ID you get back from your meta data to `get_attached_file`.

Comment: @ChipBennett I changed it. The attachment file name is stored in postmeta table with _wp_attached_file as meta_key. So I change the code. But have no success.

Comment: They still don't match. Your updated loop code has `get_attached_file( $data->ID )`, which is different from the first code block. Where do you define `$data`?

Comment: @Milo I'm passing the ID using get_the_ID(). This is not correct?

Comment: Your first code block calls `get_post_meta()`. Your loop code block calls `get_attached_file()`. Please use consistent code, describe what output you get, explain what you *expect* to happen, and what's happening unexpectedly or not happening as expected.

Comment: @ChipBennett I updated my question. With this code, I hope to get the name of the file attached to the post. This name is stored in postmeta table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your meta field contains the ID of the attachment, you need to fetch that ID, then get the filename using that attachment ID.

```
$doc_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'pdf', true );
$filename = basename( get_attached_file( $doc_id ) );
echo $filename;
```

Comment: Thanks Milo. This is exactly what I need. Just onde question: is possible to get the attachment url?

Comment: "*is possible to get the attachment url*" - the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) is your friend.