# How can I get or the intermediate size of an image with wp_get_attachment_image_src without using post meta?

Tags: images, post-meta, attachments

I'd like to get the name of an intermediate file based on it's original attachment without relying on its post meta. As the registered image sizes e.g. thumbnail have been unregistered, the post meta is unreliable.

For example, if the attachment is named `test.jpg` and when it's uploaded, it typically generates the filename `test-106x150.jpg`

If I use `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail')`, it returns an array like so:

```
[0] => https://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/test.jpeg
[1] => 106
[2] => 150
[3] =>
```

I was hoping it would be:

```
[0] => https://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/test-106x150.jpg
[1] => 106
[2] => 150
[3] =>
```

Is there another way?

Comment: Why wouldn't you get the second example? Have you unregistered `thumbnail`? Your last question suggests you might have, but you didn't mention it here. Please include all relevant information in the question.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, yes, it's unregistered. Sorry, I should have mentioned it. I've updated the question.

Comment: So you want to be able to use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` with `thumbnail` even though you've unregistered it? Why? Why is it unregistered if you want to use it?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, it's unregistered for all new files. This leaves behind a large number of orphaned files that were created that need to be deleted or removed. If the post meta is intact, I can loop through it an delete all the files. If the post meta has been overwritten, I can't find a reliable way to perform the same action.

Comment: Does this question help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20081/how-to-get-attachment-file-name-not-attachment-url